# Typescript - declaring object that only has properties of a single type?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create an object where all values are of type `SFXElem`.
Is it possible to tell TS that every value needs to be of type SFXElem? Just like `Array<string>` knows that every value in the array will be a string?

```
interface SFXElem {
    path: string,
    audio?: Audio
}

// This doesn't work: Error "Type 'Object' is not generic
const sfxDir1: Object<SFXElem> = {
    sound1: {path: "something.mp3"},
    sound2: {path: "other.mp3"},
}

// This could work, but I can sneak other types if I don't use <SFXElem> on every line
const sfxDir2 = {
    sound1: <SFXElem>{path: "hi"},
    sound2: <SFXElem>{path: "ho"},
    sound3: {other: "hello"}      // Allowed
};
```

Is there a way to tell TypeScript that only `SFXElem` types are allowed as object values?

#### Attempt 1:

I tried using `Record<string, SFXElem>`, as suggested by CRice, but that lets me access properties that don't exist. In the demo below, accessing the `doesntExist` property is allowed, when it should yield an error.

[image]

Comment: Try `Record<string, SFXElem>`. And take a look through [this very handy page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html).

Comment: @CRice Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried it, but it seems that using `Record` lets me access properties that don't exist. I updated my question with that approach under "Attempt 1".

Comment: Yeah, that's how string index signatures work... do you want it to prohibit the keys that don't exist?  Or just return `SFXElem | undefined` for each key?  Note that the former is not something that happens for a specific type, and you'd need a generic helper function.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Index Signatures.

```
interface SFXObject: {
    [index: string]: SFXElement
}
```

This way you can make an object of type `SFXObject` and every string property will need to be an `SFXElement`.

So in your case something like this:

```
const sfxDir1: SFXObject = {
    sound1: {path: "something.mp3"},
    sound2: {path: "other.mp3"},
    sound3: {other: "hello"} // Not allowed
}
```

Documentation here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html

Comment: Still allows accessing non-existed property

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Record` by listing names of properties that you want to allow:

```typescript
const sfxDir3: Record<"sound1" | "sound2", SFXElem> = {
    sound1: {path: "something.mp3"},
    sound2: {path: "other.mp3"},
};
```

It seems you are creating chicken-egg problem here. If you want to allow "any" property name on the type and only to constrain property type, then your 2nd example `Record<string, SFXelem>` is valid.

This would be valid usage for that case, to add extra property after initialization:

```typescript
const sfxList2: Record<string, SFXElem> = {
    sound1: {path: "something.mp3"},
    sound2: {path: "other.mp3"},
};

sfxList2.doesntExistsYet = {path: "yet-another.mp3"};
```

Comment: Agreed, Comparing it to `Array<string>` is wrong.